# Unable to write NSArray to file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, gdata-api

I am using google contact data objective c APIs for fetching contacts. I got contacts array from google server now i want to write contact to file. i am using `writeToFile:atomically:` method for writing array to file but This method is not working for me since i feel that output array from gdata API not contain property list objects. Please suggest any alternate solution.

```
-(void)fetchData{
    GDataServiceGoogleContact *service=[[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];
    [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
    [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
   [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:[mUsername stringValue] password:[mPassword stringValue]];

    // GENERATING THE URL
    NSURL *feedURL=[GDataServiceGoogleContact contactFeedURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
    GDataQuery *contQuery=[GDataQueryContact contactQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    [contQuery setShouldShowDeleted:YES];
    [contQuery setMaxResults:2000];
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket=[service fetchFeedWithQuery:contQuery delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(hasFetchedContacts:feed:error:)];    
}


-(void) hasFetchedContacts:(GDataServiceTicket*) ticket  feed:(GDataFeedContact*) contacts error:(NSError*) err
{
    NSArray *contactList=[contacts entries];
    NSLog(@"%d",[list writeToFile:@"/Users/subhranil/Desktop/contactList" atomically:NO]);  

}
```

Comment: maybe you can wrap the objects in a custom class that conforms to `NSCoding` protocol

Comment: Have you took a look to my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `byte` array for this purpose and `NSData` for writing to file.
For saving:

```
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[contacts entries] length:total];
[data writeToFile:@"path" atomically:YES];
```

total=  The total size of the array in bytes

For retrieving:

```
   NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path"];
   NSUInteger len = [newdata length];
   Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
   memcpy(byteData, [newdata bytes], len);
```

`byteData` will now contain an array of GDataEntryContact objects and you can use them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it up to NSData with:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:contactList];
```

Then save NSData to file with:

```
[data writeToFile:@"/Users/subhranil/Desktop/contactList" atomically:NO];
```

You can later restore the data back to NSArray using:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"yourFilePath"];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

Just **make sure** that objects inside your `NSArray` conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: This will not work in my case because GDataEntryContact does not support archiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode/decode GDataObject using an xml as generator.

Encode:

```
[entry setNamespaces:[entry completeNamespaces]];
NSString *xml = [[entry XMLElement] XMLString];
if (nil != xml) 
{
    //Store your xml NSString to a file
}
```

Decode:

```
NSString *xml = //Read your XML String from file;
NSXMLElement *xmlElement = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:xml error: &error];
if (!error) {
    return [[GDataEntryDocBase alloc] initWithXMLElement:xmlElement parent: nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you sure? This is the solution personally suggested to me by the creator of the API. I also tried to implement it and it works. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: entry is a general GDataEntryBase object. For example a single GDataEntryContactBase, (an element from GDataFeedContact).